# Changing a PHP variable by clicking a link in HTML

Tags: php, html

I want to change a variable by clicking a link, this is what I tried:

```html
<a href="#" name="link">link</a>

$var = 0;

if (isset($_GET["link"])) {
  $var = $var + 10;
}
```

But it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

I use XAMPP to run my index.php file.

Comment: PHP is a server side language, you can do it without using ajax

Comment: PHP runs on server, javascript in Browser.

Comment: `$_GET["link"]` will contains the value passed in a URL like in `example.com?link=foo`

Comment: I don't want the link to redirect the user to a URL, I just want it to refresh the page and change a variable when clicked. Is there some sort of a dummy URL that I can use?

Comment: Try setting a value in a cookie and passing it to the server like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35684778/1590073

Comment: I'm trying not to use JS for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer i will give help more if you have any problem

```
<?php
$var=$_GET['link'];
if($var==null){
$var = 0;
}
if($var!=null){
  $var = $var + 10;
}
?>
<h1><?php echo($var);?></h1>
<form action="">
  <input type="hidden" id="link" name="link" value="<?php echo($var);?>"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example for your question

```
<?php
$var=$_GET['link'];
if($var==null){
$var = 0;
}
if($var!=null){
  $var = $var + 10;
}
echo "<a href=index.php?link=",urlencode($var),">Click=  ($var)</a>";
?>
```

change index.php as per your file name

Comment: I can't try it now, but I'll get back to you if I'd need more help.